# css div stick to the border with responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have the `div.wrapper` with the `div.items` using `display:inline-block`

I want to add padding to them but I also want the items to stick to the left and right product.

How to do this with responsive?

here is my HTML

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="items">123</div>
        <div class="items">123</div>
        <div class="items">123</div>
        <div class="items">123</div>
        <div class="items">123</div>
        <div class="items">123</div>
    </div>
```

Here is the layout i want:

[image]

Comment: add padding to container (parent div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also you can use `display: flex`
and for responsive use `flex: 0 0  200px/*this is for example*/;`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.wrapper>div {
  width: 30%;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="items">123</div>
  <div class="items">123</div>
  <div class="items">123</div>
  <div class="items">123</div>
  <div class="items">123</div>
  <div class="items">123</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but he need them to stick on both left and right sides as the screenshot

Comment: thanks , i use space-between and make the layout i want.

Comment: but if the item cannot fill the row , can i make them like this ?

Comment: @fyptommy and for responsive use flex: 0 0  200px - add for children

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/

Comment: problem in last 2 divs (center align)?

Comment: yes, i want them like this :     
imgur.com/a/yhw6t

Comment: @fyptommy i find this https://codepen.io/DanAndreasson/pen/ZQXLXj

hope this help

Answer (score -1):

Make the changes accordingly , hope this will solve your problem

```
display : flex
flex-direction:row;
justify-contents:space-around
```

Comment: what changes ? try adding a complete answer, this is not helpful as you don't specify where to add this CSS

Comment: apply these styles to wrapper class,

Comment: you need to say this inside your answer so everyone understand it. Also try using snippet code to show your result